# XNA Framework "Vector2" issue. *First program...*

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

first time trying XNA Framework in C#..

followed this tutorial: http://www.uxmagic.com/blog/post/2010/08/17/e2809cHello-Worlde2809d-for-XNA-Game-Studio-40.aspx

Everything's ok until the line where it says to add the following:

```
Vector2 playerPosition=vector2.zero;
```

Before this line, I can display my texture, close the window with esc. etc, the whole thing seems fairly straightfoward.

But when I got the whole code written, lauching the game give me this error...

```
The name 'vector2' does not exist in the current context
```

Am I missing an import or something ? Thanks ! Here's the full code because it's not on the actual website, obviously.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace WindowsGame2
{

    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Texture2D playerTexture;
        Vector2 playerPosition = vector2.zero;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            playerTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("character1");
            //base.LoadContent();
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {

        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                this.Exit();

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
                playerPosition.X--;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
                playerPosition.X++;

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            //spriteBatch.Draw(playerTexture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(playerTexture, playerPosition, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Vector2 playerPosition = vector2.zero;
```

That line. Change `vector2.zero` to `Vector2.Zero`

C# is case-sensitive language which is the reason why "vector2.zero" doesn't work.

Pretty much every C# library ( atleast Microsoft's libraries ) uses these casing conventions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx

Although, many people ( myself included ) use underscore ("_") for private/protected instance variables.

Answer (score 2):

Change the line to

```
Vector2 playerPosition=Vector2.Zero;
```

C# is case sensitive, so **v** ector2 is not **V** ector2

Comment: @MattDavey: I don't know what you're on about. ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
Vector2 playerPosition=Vector2.Zero;
```

Capital V on Vector2 and capital Z on zero.